# Strapi mongodd de-populate

Tags: strapi

Is there any way to prevent a call like this `strapi.services.MODEL_NAME.find(query)` from populating its relations?

In my specific case I have a simple Message model:

`"attributes": {
    "body": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "required": true,
      "maxLength": 300
    },
    "chat": {
      "model": "chat"
    },
    "user": {
      "model": "user",
      "plugin": "users-permissions"
    }
  }`

and in a particular case I wish not to populate user & chat, just reference their IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in my case the solution would be to add an empty array:

```
strapi.services.MODEL_NAME.find(query, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `autoPopulate` option to false.

```
"user": {
  "model": "user",
  "plugin": "users-permissions",
  "autoPopulate": false
}
```

Comment: Thank you. One more thing - why does strapi.services.FANCYMODEL.update() have to return a "populated" response? In my case, "FANCYMODEL" has 3 relations and they all get populated on successful update and it takes ~270-300ms. If I just call FANCYMODEL.findOneAndUpdate my response is not populated and it takes only 40ms to achieve the same result. Sometimes you simply dont need it populated and the price to pay is way too high (270ms v 40ms)

Comment: Perhaps some flag can be added to the internal update() method to avoid populate

Comment: It is interesting feedback. Thank you so much! I will check that with the team.